# Issue with converting deprecated D3DXMATRIX

Tags: c++, directx-11

Whenever I was converting old Dx11 code to up to date Dx11 code, I was having issues with D3DXMatrix as the documentation wasn't very clear on how to convert this, so how do you go about converting a D3DXMATRIX? -Answer Below

Comment: Although there is a good question implied here, I think this needs some work as there isn't actually a question asked...

Comment: Yeah....I had never answered my own question before so I wasn't really sure how to format it...I'll edit it, thanks for the feedback

Comment: Sorry, I just saw that MSDN is indeed missing an entry in the type tables for D3DXMATRIX. It should probably list "XMFLOAT4X4" or "XMMATRIX" depending on context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`D3DXMATRIX` is deprecated, you instead need to use an `XMMATRIX`.

You'll have to include DirectXMath.h, and then use the `DirectX` namespace. Finally, you may have issues even still with using `XMMATRIX` because it doesn't align properly in some cases, if this is the case, use `DirectX::CXMMATRIX`, this will allow for proper alignment. With that, you should be good to go.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [SimpleMath](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/SimpleMath) in the [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK) as this helps smooth over the strict alignment requirements of ``XMMATRIX`` and the need to explicitly load/store ``XMFLOAT4X4`` types from data structures in DirectXMath. With SimpleMath, you'd use ``DirectX::SimpleMath::Matrix``.